# Spring 3 : Can't find AuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

I'm not able to find `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` when migrating from `Spring 2` to `Spring 3` (using spring-core)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This class has been renamed to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring security 3.x.

ref : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationProcessingFilter.html

Comment: Do you mean "AuthenticationProcessingFilter"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for constants which were available in spring 3 in **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY** 
That is no longer available in that class.

Alternative is spring has added **WebAttributes** class **org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes** in which you can get the same exception using the below code -
**session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]**

In WebAttributes AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION is string defined as below
WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY"

Hopefully this helps.