# Can't find some deprecated constant variables in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, deprecated

I'm **`upgrading spring security`** from `2.0.5` to `4.2.0`, I know its quite a big upgrade, But I have to do that. All configuration errors are resolved, but Now having some errors in some java codes. I have already solved some of it.
The errors I'm having now is like my project is using some Constants from class 
 `AuthenticationProcessingFilter`, those are
 `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY`,
 `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY` and 
`SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY` , 
here I've solved the problem with `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY` 
as I used `WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION`, But can't find any alternatives for rest two. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3 : Can't find AuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536030/spring-3-cant-find-authenticationprocessingfilter) use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter instead

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter didn't have the constants I mensioned.

Comment: The answer has been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550103/6396924

Answer (score 0):

> Usually, a migration from Spring Security 2 to Spring Security 3 is
> straightforward. However, if you implemented custom spring security
> filters, chances are you will have a bit more work. The basic filter
> class from the Spring Security specific SpringSecurityFilter changed
> to the generic Spring web GenericFilterBean and the API of this class
> changed a lot more than the API of other classes.
>
> Especially
> AbstractProcessingFilter(now AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter)
> changed. In Spring Security 3.0, the determineFailureUrl and
> determineTargetUrl methods were removed in favour of adding separate
> Handler instances(AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
> AuthenticationFailureHandler,..) to these classes, which makes the
> filters more configurable/reusable. A similar story for
> LogoutFilter(determineRedirectUrl removed in favour of adding a
> LogoutSuccessHandler).

Do the [Spring 2 to 3](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/04/30/migrating-from-spring-security-2-to-spring-security-3/) migration requirements then [Spring 3 to 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework)